# Show JQuery UI Autocomplete suggestions on top of other elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using JQuery UI Autocomplete to suggest different cities on a map control. I usually have other divs showing content that interfere with the suggestions from the autocomplete. The divs appear on top of the suggestions.

Changing the z-index of these divs is pointles for the suggestions have the lowest z-index.

The chosen strategy is to modify the z-index of the suggestions to appear on top. The idea is to attach a handler to the load event of the suggestions that changes the z-index to the highest value. As suggestions are not available at control creation time, the handler must be attached using .live(). I've done the following:

```
$('ul.ui-autocomplete').live('load',function(){
this.css('z-index',3999);
});
```

The problem seems that I'm not attaching the handler well as it's not getting fired. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround to make it work. I do not really like it as it depends on timing the search of the dropdown list a few seconds to "ensure" it will be available. You need this because when open event is triggered the dropdownlist hasnt been created yet. If you register the following function to the open event

```
function() {
  $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
  setTimeout("$('ul.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index',3999)",500);
}
```

though this works, i'm still looking for a deterministic response.

Answer (score 0):

use this option below line of code:

```
$(".selector").autocomplete("option", "position", {my: "right top", at: "right bottom"});
```